# java - reading 2 byte integer in 2's complement from binary file into integer

Tags: java, int, byte, data-conversion, bitmask

I am trying to parse a binary file containing values. In the specs it says that each value is *represented as a 2-byte integer in 2's complement format*.
I am reading the file into a byte array called 'data':

```
int i = (data[i] & 0xff) | (short) (data[i+1] << 8);
```

The values look fine however when I try to write them back into the file:

```
byte a = (byte)((tempInt >> 8) & 0xff);
byte b = (byte)(tempInt & 0xff);
```

'tempInt' being the value in int.

When I read in the file that I wrote, not all of the values are the same.
Some of them but not all.

Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE:**
I plottet the values for comparison.
The top half are the values that i read from the file.
The bottom half are the values that i read from the file, then wrote to a new file and then read again.
[image: plot]
I think that the graphs look too similar for it to be completely wrong.

**UPDATE #2:**
the bytes i read from the input file:

```
0, 0, 59, 36, 40, 36, 23, 36, 54, 36, 54, 36, 41, 36, 46, 36, 50, 36, 52, 36, 79, 36, 79, 36, 66, 36, 65, 36, 58, 36, 58, 36, 58, 36, 45, 36, 51, 36, 65, 36, 65, 36, 76, 36, 78, 36, 69, 36, 54, 36, 68, 36, 86, 36, 85, 36, 81, 36, 81, 36, 80, 36, 84, 36, 84, 36, 80, 36, 82, 36, 85, 36, 81, 36, 80, 36, 75, 36, 75, 36, 79, 36, 91, 36, 83, 36, 64, 36, 71, 36, 79, 36, 56, 36, 38, 36, 47, 36, 51, 36, 41, 36, 48, 36, 63, 36, 56, 36, 50, 36, 57, 36, 67, 36, 78, 36, 81, 36, 67, 36, 81, 36, 81, 36, 82, 36, 69, 36, 66, 36, 66, 36, 54, 36, 39, 36, 78, 36, 78, 36, 78, 36, 62, 36, 57, 36, 73, 36, 75, 36, 69, 36, 76, 36, 81, 36, 74, 36
```

Converted integers:

```
0, 9275, 9256, 9239, 9270, 9270, 9257, 9262, 9266, 9268, 9295, 9295, 9282, 9281, 9274, 9274, 9274, 9261, 9267, 9281, 9281, 9292, 9294, 9285, 9270, 9284, 9302, 9301, 9297, 9297, 9296, 9300, 9300, 9296, 9298, 9301, 9297, 9296, 9291, 9291, 9295, 9307, 9299, 9280, 9287, 9295, 9272, 9254, 9263, 9267, 9257, 9264, 9279, 9272, 9266, 9273, 9283, 9294, 9297, 9283, 9297, 9297, 9298, 9285, 9282, 9282, 9270, 9255, 9294, 9294, 9294, 9278, 9273, 9289, 9291, 9285, 9292, 9297, 9290
```

the bytes i read from the file that i wrote from the above values:

```
32, 0, 0, 36, 59, 36, 40, 36, 23, 36, 54, 36, 54, 36, 41, 36, 46, 36, 50, 36, 52, 36, 79, 36, 79, 36, 66, 36, 65, 36, 58, 36, 58, 36, 58, 36, 45, 36, 51, 36, 65, 36, 65, 36, 76, 36, 78, 36, 69, 36, 54, 36, 68, 36, 86, 36, 85, 36, 81, 36, 81, 36, 80, 36, 84, 36, 84, 36, 80, 36, 82, 36, 85, 36, 81, 36, 80, 36, 75, 36, 75, 36, 79, 36, 91, 36, 83, 36, 64, 36, 71, 36, 79, 36, 56, 36, 38, 36, 47, 36, 51, 36, 41, 36, 48, 36, 63, 36, 56, 36, 50, 36, 57, 36, 67, 36, 78, 36, 81, 36, 67, 36, 81, 36, 81, 36, 82, 36, 69, 36, 66, 36, 66, 36, 54, 36, 39, 36, 78, 36, 78, 36, 78, 36, 62, 36, 57, 36, 73, 36, 75, 36, 69, 36, 76, 36, 81, 36
```

Converted integers:

```
32, 9216, 9275, 9256, 9239, 9270, 9270, 9257, 9262, 9266, 9268, 9295, 9295, 9282, 9281, 9274, 9274, 9274, 9261, 9267, 9281, 9281, 9292, 9294, 9285, 9270, 9284, 9302, 9301, 9297, 9297, 9296, 9300, 9300, 9296, 9298, 9301, 9297, 9296, 9291, 9291, 9295, 9307, 9299, 9280, 9287, 9295, 9272, 9254, 9263, 9267, 9257, 9264, 9279, 9272, 9266, 9273, 9283, 9294, 9297, 9283, 9297, 9297, 9298, 9285, 9282, 9282, 9270, 9255, 9294, 9294, 9294, 9278, 9273, 9289, 9291, 9285, 9292, 9297
```

**UPDATE #3:**
Okay, so I made a small version of the programm, where I just read in bytes from a file converted them to integers, converted them back to bytes and wrote them to a file. Without the whole data format. 
And it actually worked. So the problem is with the algorithm and not with the byte to int (and back to byte) conversion.
I will go back and check the algorithm.
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you're *reading* them in little-endian format (the first value is the least important) but you're *writing* them in big-endian format (the first value is the most important), assuming you're writing `a` then `b`.

Just reverse the order when you write them, assuming the file is meant to be little-endian:

```
byte a = (byte)(tempInt & 0xff);
byte b = (byte)((tempInt >> 8) & 0xff);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :)
i changed the order however the values are still a little different.
i plottet the values for comparison in the update

Comment: @cmplx96: Plotting graphs like that isn't nearly as useful as providing sample input and output *numbers*, ideally with a [mcve]. (We have very little idea of how that graph was really generated - what else there is beyond "read the number, write the number".)

Comment: I added the values. There is nothing else. I read the file, store it in integer and then store it back to bytes.

Comment: @cmplx96: So show the code that does that. Provide a [mcve] so we can try it for ourselves. I would look carefully at the very first byte, for one thing...

Comment: @cmplx96: The edit you've made is far from a [mcve]. A minimal example would *just* read the values and then write them back to another file.

Comment: that is actually what i posted. a function that reads the file and a function that writes it.

Comment: @cmplx96: That's neither minimal (it does more than it needs to) nor complete (I can't copy/paste/compile/run).

Comment: the way that the data format is structured, i don't think that there is a way to do it minimal.
you need the loops and the offsets or else the values are wrong.

Comment: @cmplx96: Not if the problem is just reading and writing the values. All you need is a file with the values in - read and write them. If that works, then you know the problem *isn't* with reading and writing the values. It sounds like you haven't really worked out where the problem is yet. Note that the example doesn't need to read and write your *actual* files - just samples with the same bits of data in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int i = ((short)data[i] & 0xff) |  ((short)data[i+1] << 8);
```

As `data` is an array of `byte`, the value `data[i+1] << 8` is done over 8 bits, yielding a zero value. I just casted the value `data[i+1]` into `shrt` before shifting left.

Comment: The `<<` operator will perform binary numeric promotion, so the shift is never done on byte values anyway. For example: `byte b = 1; int x = b << 8; System.out.println(x);` prints 256.